# Static pages showing post name in place of their contents when i display post in navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, post, navigation

I am displaying category and all its posta in my top navigation using below code for the post:-

```
$arguments = array('category' => 3 , 'order' => 'ASC', );
    $posts = get_posts($arguments); ?>
    foreach($posts as $post) 
    { 
           setup_postdata($post); ?>
           <li><a href="#"> <?php the_title(); ?></li>
```

But when i do this my all static pages include home will not display their contents and display only a post from that category .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you tried [wp_reset_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query).try wp_reset_query after foreach

edit:-

use [query post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instant of get_posts

```
$arguments = array('cat' => 3 , 'order' => 'ASC', );


// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query($arguments);

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

wp_reset_postdata will reset your post data.this query will not affect your other pages